# SQL Server 2005 - Mailqueues use UTC time instead of local time

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, timezone, getdate

This is more of a question than a problem as our production system is working as intended.

I am relatively new to the SQL environment. I've been poking through various configurations on the server just to get myself familiarized with the system. One thing that I noticed is the mail queues seem to use the UTC time instead of the local time. For example, if I run

```
exec sysmail_help_queue_sp
```

The last empty_rowset_time column shows a time that is exactly 12 hours behind the value `getdate()` returns (I am in New Zealand) and happens to coincide with the value of `getutcdate()`. I was more than a little surprised to say the least. The server is configured with the correct time zone (Auckland/Wellington).

I have made sure that the value(s) in the `last_empty_rowset_time` is indeed updated every time I `sp_send_dbmail`.

Does anyone know why this is the case? I am just curious to know. I do apologize for my newbiness if this sounds obvious to some of you.

Thanks.

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something that is affected by local configuration.  Based on documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187400.aspx

Microsoft explicitly states "military time format and GMT time zone".  If you want to see it in your local time zone you'll have to modify your query as such.

Comment: That'll teach me for not reading the article (yep, I did 'read' it before posting here) thoroughly. I do thank you for taking your time to reply!